# Drawing 6 imageviews inside 1 cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I have a very annoying problem. What I want to do is to draw 6 imageviews into one cell. On the following screens you see what I want to achieve.

- [Screen what I want to achieve](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8050170687/)
- [Screen what I have now](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8071984693/in/photostream/)

This is what I am doing in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        float xCoord = 30.0;
        Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team.image]];
        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord,0,66,66)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
        xCoord += imgView.frame.size.width + 5;
        NSLog(@"%f",xCoord);
        [cell.contentView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after you fix the bug with calculating the `x` coordinate that get reset back to 30 in each iteration, you will have the issue with reusing cells: your program adds new `UIImageView`s to the cell, even though it may contain five `UIImageView` objects already. After a few rounds of reusing, the cell would have a few dozen images sitting atop of each other, with a disastrous effects on the performance - especially the performance of scrolling.

You should define a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` with six `UIImageView` objects added as subviews, give it a method like this

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage*)image forPosition:(NSUInteger)position;
```

and call this method in the loop (if you want six images, the loop should have `i <= 5`, not `i < 5` as its ending condition).

**EDIT :** Here is an oversimplified way to code this:

CustomCell.h:

```
#define NUM_PICS 6

@interface SixPicsCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIImageView *pics[NUM_PICS];
}
-(void)setImage:(UIImage*)image forPosition:(NSUInteger)position;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
@end
```

CustomCell.m:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != NUM_PICS ; i++) {
            pics[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
            [pics[i] setFrame:CGRectMake(30+71*i, 0, 66, 66)];
            [self.contentView addSubview:pics[i]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setImage:(UIImage*)image forPosition:(NSUInteger)position {
    pics[position].image = image;
}
```

Comment: Oké I placed this function in my customCell.h but how do I implement this in my customCell.m ?

Comment: And how to I go to the next indexPath when it sets the image?

Comment: @StefGeelen Take a look at the edit, it should give you a few ideas of how this approach can be implemented.

Comment: it crashes at pics[position].image = image with this error -[UILabel setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa02bf70

Comment: @StefGeelen Could you post your updated code somewhere? It looks like there's a memory corruption issue there. You're on ARC, right?

Comment: I'm trying it at a different way, you can follow the question over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821250/filling-up-an-custom-tableviewcell-with-images

Answer (score 0):

LOL, I've answered this before for this exact problem.

The (by far) easiest way of doing this is to use a UICollectionView (but IIRC you wanted to roll out to iOS 5).

To solve the problem of reuse and memory (and also to make it possible to have unlimited entries in each row) you can use a custom cUITableViewCell that contains its own UITableView (rotated by 90 degrees).  Then this can display as many images as you want as each image is then inside it's own cell again.

It sound complicated but if you break it down it really isn't.

Comment: Do you maybe have some example ?

Comment: I've only done this once myself.  You will need to subclass UITabelViewCell and in your subclassed cell add a UITableView and make the cell the UITabelViewCellDataSource (and Delegate).  Then in your first table you pass the cell an array of images.  Then in the cell you can display those images.  As long as you subclass the cell and keep the code separate it should be fairly easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

this is a case of a grid view..

try the following for your reference

```
int rows  = 5;
int columns = 4 //

for (int j=0; j<rows; j++) {

    int xPos=0;
    for (int i=0; i<columns; i++) {

         UIImageView *backImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3+xPos,3+yPos, 104, 140)];
        [backImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image.png"]];
        [backImg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
          [cell.contentView addSubView:backImg];               

        xPos+=105;



    }//columns end
    yPos +=140;

}//rows end
```